# Task<IResult>'s handling of List<IResult> return types

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following line of code to work with. Problem is that the compiler keeps complaining of this line. Note that the expression in contained within an async method of it's own, hence the use of the await keyword, and the called method also is an async method with an async call. The 2 code samples are as below

```
var tresultString = await Task.FromResult(TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath));
```

or

```
var tresultString = await Task.FromResult<List<IResultAd>>(TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath));
```

when I access the returns without using Task.FromResult, I get the type

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IResultAd]]
```

as my return type.

The errors I get are

1. The best overloaded method match for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>>(System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>)` has some invalid arguments
2. The best overloaded method match for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>>(System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd)` has some invalid arguments
3. Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>`
4. Argument 1: cannot convert from `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>'`

Here is an example from MSDN

```
// TASK<T> EXAMPLE
async Task<int> TaskOfT_MethodAsync()
{
    // The body of the method is expected to contain an awaited asynchronous 
    // call. 
    // Task.FromResult is a placeholder for actual work that returns a string. 
    var today = await Task.FromResult<string>(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString());

    // The method then can process the result in some way. 
    int leisureHours;
    if (today.First() == 'S')
        leisureHours = 16;
    else
        leisureHours = 5;

    // Because the return statement specifies an operand of type int, the 
    // method must have a return type of Task<int>. 
    return leisureHours;
}
```

All for the same line of code above. I would appreciate any help in understanding the issue with the code samples please. Thanks in advance.

Signature of the method TestDataRepositoryAsync:

```
private async Task<List<IResultAd>> TestDataRepositoryAsync(String filePath)
{
    using (var testfilestream =  File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        var getJsonStringFromFile = new StreamReader(testfilestream).ReadToEndAsync();
        var jsonString = await getJsonStringFromFil);
        List<IAdvertisement> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IResultAd>>(jsonString);
        return result;
    }
    return null; 
}
```

[image]

[image]

Result property of Task gives me access to the result I expect.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `FromResult` here in the first place, especially if you're just going to `await` it right away anyway?  Just don't do either.

Comment: `await Task.FromResult(X)` can simply be rewritten as `X`. `Task.FromResult(X)` creates a task that immediately completes with result `X`, and `await` gives this result. Perhaps you just want `await TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath)`?

Comment: No, I want to return a List<IResult> from the process. I used the example from msdn as an example. Basically, the call to TestDataRepository(testfilePath) returns a System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd>> and  Task.FromResult is a placeholder for actual work that returns a the List<IresultAd> itself.

Comment: But the result of `await TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath)` *is* `List<IResult>`.

Comment: No, the result is System.Threading.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd‌​>>. I had tried simply accessing it as a List but that continously failed.

Comment: I did that and the return type, as I have posted above, is System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.Collections.Generic.List1[IResultAd]]

Comment: That suggests that `TestDataRepositoryAsync` is incorrectly written -- if `await` gives you a `Task`, that means the return type of `TestDataRepositoryAsync` is `Task<Task<..>>`, which seems a bit redundant. In any case, adding `.FromResult()` will do you no good. As silly as this is, try `await (await TestDataRepositoryAsync(...))`

Comment: I think you should post a sample of `TestDataRepositoryAsync` (signature, declaration of the variable returned and `return` statement) so that everybody gets a clear idea of what you're trying to achieve. There's something weird going on in there.

Comment: In a minute, but I just added an image to show what the return type continues to be

Comment: I posted the code up there now

Comment: OK, and what exactly is the problem when you `await TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath)`? That should give you your `List<IResultAd>`. No?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, that really helps! In the screenshot, I see `var resultString = TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath)`. Could you try `var results = await TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath)`? (The variable should be renamed because it's not a string.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Didn't you suggest that 30 minutes ago?

Comment: @PatriceGahide: Indeed I did, but it doesn't look like the OP did what I asked. If they did, and the response they posted was accurate, that would be surprising.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's understandable, sometimes we're so stuck into the problem that we don't even properly read possible solutions, convinced that we already tried it.

Comment: I explained that I already tried that and posted return type for you to see --> System.Threading.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd‌​>>

Comment: @user272671 It really can't be or I am missing something big. `var results = await TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath);` with the implementation you posted => `results` will be of type `List<IResultAd>`. How do you check that to see a `System.Threading.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<IResultAd‌​>>`?

Comment: It's up there in the image, well when I tried without the await. But yes, that is how I check it, Hover and scroll through the menu

Comment: @user272671 Mate, I don't want to be rude but you have to *read* the comments. Jeroen and I used the `await` keyword in our statements. I don't see it in your image.

Comment: @user272671 If you don't `await`, you get back the `Task`, this is expected. Then you can do whatever you want with it, but if you need the results right away, you just `await` for it.

Comment: I know, I said I used it and I got the same thing. I mean the signature of the method depicts the return type would be of Task<List<IResultAd>> so, why do not think that that should not be the case? I am posting another shorter example for you to see

Comment: Because that's how TPL works. Check the MSDN example you posted. See how it returns an `int`, even if the signature says `Task<int>`? When you `await` a call to that method, you get your `int` back. That's the beauty of it.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. I need to access the Result property to get at my returned result. Thanks all. I don't know why it does not seem to work as you said it should but I am able to access the result from the Result Property of the Task<IList<IResultAd>> object returned which is great for me.

Comment: `Task.Result` will get you back the result, but your code will block and wait for the result to be available -- in other words, it runs synchronously. `await Task` is asynchronous and doesn't have this issue. Which one is most appropriate depends on whether you are in a sync or async method.

Comment: In my case, I had to access Result to get it, and when I did query the expression, it does show that the Result property  is what I  need to access in my case. Image above.

Comment: @user272671 No you don't. Result blocks and returns the unwrapped result. `await` waits asynchronously then returns the unwrapped result. The only way you can get a Task<T> instead of `T` from `await` is if the original return value was a `Task<Task<T>`, or if you are checking the wrong variable to begin with. In your second screenshot you are *not* checking the result of await but the result of `ReadAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the call to `Task.FromResult` is unnecessary. Your code should be:

```
var tresultString = await TestDataRepositoryAsync(testfilePath);
```

Note that the MSDN example explicitly states that it's using `Task.FromResult` *as a placeholder for asynchronous work*, in your case, `TestDataRepositoryAsync`.

On a side note, when you're using asynchronous file streams, you must be sure to open them explicitly for asynchronous access:

```
using (var testfilestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to access the  Result Property of the Task returned.

[image]

Comment: @Gary This answer was posted by the author.